# Fine-Tune Vicuna with GCP: increase quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I want to train vicuna with my own data using Google Cloud Plattform. To make it easier I want to do this with SkyPilot (https://github.com/skypilot-org/skypilot) like it is described here: https://github.com/lm-sys/FastChat#fine-tuning-on-any-cloud-with-skypilot In GCP I don't have the required 8 A100 GPUs with 80GB memory in my quota right now.

When I request to approve a higher quota for A100 GPUs with 80GB memory in europe-west1, my request will be rejected.

I have valid paying information but my GCP Account is brand new.

What can I do to get the GPUs in my quota?

Comment: We cannot help you with a vendor's policy. A quota increase is similar to a credit line increase for a credit card. The simple answer is that you will have to wait until you have a payment history. If you are a business, contact Google Cloud Sales and establish a relationship and credit line.